# "Cannot implicity convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exits(are you missing a cast?) (C80266)"

Tags: c#

tengo un bug con la variable 'precio' (private double[] precio) que intentando usar el método 'NumeroDeAccesor', sale el bug que aparece en el título.
Si le quieren echar un vistazo al código, aquí se los dejo:

```
    // Escritura-Lectura de variables
    public int NumeroDeAccesor(int numeroA) // Escritura
    {
        numeroAccesor = numeroA;
        return numeroAccesor;
    }
    public int NumeroDeAccesor() // Lectura
    {
        return numeroAccesor;
    }

    public string Nombre
    {
        set
        {
            nombre[NumeroDeAccesor()] = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return nombre[NumeroDeAccesor()];
        }
    }
    public string Marca
    {
        set
        {
            marca[NumeroDeAccesor()] = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return marca[NumeroDeAccesor()];
        }
    }
    public int Precio
    {
        set
        {
            precio[NumeroDeAccesor()] = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return precio[Convert.ToDouble(NumeroDeAccesor())];             }
    }
}
```

Nota: el lenguaje utilizado es c#

¡Saludos!

Comment: No entiendo que quires implementar con ese codigo, Si usas array los indices son numericos enteros, no veo porque aplicar un `Convert.ToDouble` eso esta mal.

Answer (score 2):

El error es claro y conciso. Tal vez no lo entiendes por estar en inglés, te lo traduzco:

> Cannot implicity convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exits (are you missing a cast?)

> No se puede convertir el tipo 'double' a 'int' implícitamente. Existe una conversión explícita (¿Estás olvidando una conversión?).

Por lo tanto, en esta expresión:

```
return precio[Convert.ToDouble(NumeroDeAccesor())];
//            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <---- Espera que esta expresión sea 'int'.
```

El compilador espera recibir un `int` pero recibe un `double` (`Convert.ToDouble(NumeroDeAccesor())`). Pasar de número de doble precisión a entero es una pérdida de precisión y C# prohíbe esta pérdida implícita, pero puedes forzarla explícitamente:

```
return precio[(int)Convert.ToDouble(NumeroDeAccesor())];
//            ^^^^^ <---- Conversión explícita
```

Lo cuál, es una tontería, ya que `NumeroDeAccesor()` ya devuelve un entero:

```
return precio[NumeroDeAccesor()];
```

Comment: Hola PaperBirdMaster, tienes razón, el error era muy fácil de corregir Le agradezco mucho su respuesta. ¡Saludos!